# CERN ROOT: saving into file tree with branch of vector of custom class

Tags: c++, io, root-framework

How can I save into a TFile a TTree with a branch of vectors of custom class?

Also, why I am I not able to load the shared library (`gSystem->Load` returns 1) generated by the `gInterpreter->GenerateDictionary` call?

Below is what I tried to do:

```cpp
// file: test.C
// 
#include "TInterpreter.h"
#include "TRandom3.h"
#include "TFile.h"
#include "TTree.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
/***************************************************************/
class MyStruct : public TObject
{
public:
 Int_t a;
 Float_t b;
 MyStruct() {a=0; b=0.0;}
 ClassDef(MyStruct,1)
};
/***************************************************************/
void test(void)
{
 gInterpreter->GenerateDictionary("std::vector<MyStruct>", "vector");
 std::vector<MyStruct> test(3);

 // fill 'test' with random numbers
 TRandom3 rnd;
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
     test[i].a = int( rnd.Gaus(3.0, 10.0) );
     test[i].b = rnd.Gaus(300.0, 10.0);
     std::cout<<"test["<<i<<"]="<<test[i].a<<' '<<test[i].b<<std::endl;
 }// end of for

 // create a TTree and (attempt to) save it into a file
 TFile outputTreeFile("test.root", "recreate");
 TTree tree("tree", "ROOT tree");
 tree.Branch("test", &test);
 tree.Fill();
 tree.Write();
}// end of function
/***************************************************************/
```

Running the code gives:

```
$ root.exe -t -l test.C+
root [0]
Processing test.C+...
test[0] = 12 295.652
test[1] = 10 299.699
test[2] = 11 299.433
Error in <TTree::Branch>: The class requested (vector<MyStruct>)
for the branch "test" is an instance of an stl collection and does
not have a compiled CollectionProxy. Please generate the
dictionary for this collection (vector<MyStruct>) to avoid to
write corrupted data.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the ROOT forum? Maybe [this thread](https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/saving-custom-classes-in-root6/20054) can help...